# Multilingual Site and Search Functions

Tags: search

Have set up an site in various languages with the structure as follows:

*en/template/article*

There's just one channel field group with the custom fields set as

*field_en, field_de, field_fr*

Etc, etc

Main issue though is when trying to implement a Simple Search functionality: the channel field parameters where you set the URL for search results only allow one input - probably will have to be *en/template* - and you cannot put {segment_1}/template which would obviously dynamically allow setting of the results page in different languages.

Has anyone encountered this one and come up with a workaround?

Comment: One question! Will all pages have versions in all languages? If not, you can use one different channel for every language. All the three can use the same field group. You can set one relationship field to chose the translated versions.

Comment: Hi Robson - yes they will but it is already set up where each channel has the fields like field1_en, field1_es etc. There's no way to change this now and extrapolate the languages into different channels.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was suggesting the same solution I used on a similar case.